# How to find the unit normal vector given only the equation of the plane?

Tags: differential-geometry, vectors

In the textbook of Differential Geometry by Do Carmo, there is this example:

For a plane $ax+by+cz+d=0$, the unit normal vector is $N=(a,b,c)/\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}$.

I am trying to understand how did they get the unit normal vector.

My try:

I first parametrise the plane by $\textbf{x}(u,v)=(-\frac{b}{a}u-\frac{c}{a}v-\frac{d}{a},u,v)$. Then $\textbf{x}_u=(-\frac{b}{a},1,0)$ and $\textbf{x}_v=(-\frac{c}{a},0,1)$. So $\textbf{x}_u\times \textbf{x}_v=(1,\frac{b}{a},\frac{c}{a})$ and $|\textbf{x}_u\times \textbf{x}_v|=\frac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}{\sqrt{a^2}}$. So $N=\frac{\sqrt{a^2}(1,\frac{b}{a},\frac{c}{a})}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}$.

There is no way I could get $N=(a,b,c)/\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}$ unless $a>0$, but there is no such mention in the problem.

Could somebody please give some light on this? Thanks.

Comment: First try when d is 0. Then you see that ABC is perpendicular to xyz.

Comment: @AHusain Yes, you're right. But does that help? What if d is not 0?

Comment: There are two normal vectors to a plane and sqrt( a^2) = abs(a). If a is positive then you get the formula Do Carmo proposes directly, if a is negative then abs( a) = -a and you have a normal vector antiparallel to the one Do Carmo proposes, either one is correct.

Comment: In the case of plane through the origin, all such $(x,y,z)$ are also tangent to the plane, so asking for something perpendicular to all of them turns into something proportional to $(a,b,c)$, you can then normalize and pick either direction. You then translate this picture away from the origin to get d back.

Comment: you seriously lack of taste

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you get the vector $\vec{x}_u\times\vec{x}_v=(1,b/a,c/a)$ you obtain its length getting
$$|\vec{x}_u\times\vec{x}_v|=\sqrt{1+b^2/a^2+c^2/a^2}$$
For now let's say that the length is given by
$$|\vec{x}_u\times\vec{x}_v|=\pm\frac{|a|\sqrt{1+b^2/a^2+c^2/a^2}}{a}$$
$$=\pm\frac{\sqrt{a^2}\sqrt{1+b^2/a^2+c^2/a^2}}{a}$$
$$=\pm\frac{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}{a}$$
(We can do this because $|a|/a=\pm 1$ depending on the sign of $a$). Then dividing our vector $\vec{x}_u\times\vec{x}_v$ by its length to normalize it we get
$$\vec{N}=\frac{\vec{x}_u\times\vec{x}_v}{|\vec{x}_u\times\vec{x}_v|}$$
$$=\pm\frac{a(1,b/a,c/a)}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}$$
$$=\pm\frac{(a,b,c)}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}$$
Which as you can see means the issue at hand just boils down to the choosing the orientation of the normal vector, which by convention we choose it by picking the plus sign in the above equation.

Comment: @Anonymous 1) Chill its like 25 points. 2) He was probably already capable of deriving a result similar to you, but his question was more so directed at why the book could ignore negative values of $a$, not why the provided unit vector works.